# Openstreetmap how to increase zoom granularity using Java

Tags: java, zooming, openstreetmap, jmapviewer

I basically manipulated this code http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/viewer/jmapviewer/src/org/openstreetmap/gui/jmapviewer/Demo.java to view an openstreetmap using java swing.

I'm having problems with the zoom functionality. Zoom can only be an integer but the difference between two zoom levels is pretty big. How can I zoom at a more granular level? I found https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/14324/openlayers-control-zoom-level-granularity but it's not java and I dont know how to make it work with Java.

Any help/references is much appreciated! I've been stuck on this for a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually read the answers of the link you posted?

OpenStreetMap [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) are usually rendered for specific [zoom levels](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Zoom_levels). If you want tiles of a different zoom level then you either need to interpolate or [render your own tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering).

Comment: I did read it but there was no code so I dont see how it can be done in Java